# search 2 strings and prepend string3 at the beginning of matched line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I want to search 1st string 'abc' in each line of a file and if exists, search for 2nd string 'xyz' on the same matched line, then prepend 3rd string '//' at the beginning of matched line.

I tried below command, but it only prints output but does not make changes to existing file. Please help here.

`grep 'abc' myfile | grep 'xyz' | sed 's/^/\/\//'`

Comment: `sed -i 's,.*\(abc.*xyz\|xyz.*abc\),//&,' file` with GNU sed.

Comment: `awk '/abc/ && /xyz/{$0="//" $0}1' myfile` Then read about replacing inplace in a file with awk

Comment: ... and keeping the same field separator if it is not a space, or if you need to keep spacing intact.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It works. Next step is, match 3 strings (abc xyz //) and delete only //. How to do this?

Comment: @firebolt Can you provide an example string with expected output? I could not post an answer as I needed something credible to showcase the solution.

Comment: Also, please ask a "final" question, do not add "steps", we are not a copilot here.

Comment: Sure, noted. If I want to revert this change, from // abc xyz to abc xyz, how do I do that? Search 3 strings in same line (abc, xyz, & //), on found, delete // from that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe 'm{abc} and m{xyz} and $_ = "//$_"; ' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)
- [`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. If I want to revert this change, from // abc xyz to abc xyz, how do I do that? Search 3 strings in same line (abc, xyz, & //), on found, delete // from that line.

Comment: @firebolt To revert the change: `perl -i.bak -lpe 'm{abc} and m{xyz} and s{^//}{}; ' in_file`. Here, `s{PATTERN}{STRING}` is replacing `PATTERN` with `STRING`, and `^` is the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just let sed do the the work for you searching for some "xyz" following "abc".

```
sed -E 's/(^.*abc.*xyz.*$)/\/\/ \1/'
```

Since you want to change the contents of a file, issue

```
sed -iE 's/(^.*abc.*xyz.*$)/\/\/ \1/' myfile
```

## Tests

```
timor@foo ~ $ echo "asdlökfjasdf abc äalsdfkgjölsaädkfgj xy" | sed -E 's/(^.*abc.*xyz.*$)/\/\/ \1/'
asdlökfjasdf abc äalsdfkgjölsaädkfgj xy
```

```
timor@foo ~ $ echo "asdlökfjasdf abc äalsdfkgjölsaädkfgj xyz" | sed -E 's/(^.*abc.*xyz.*$)/\/\/ \1/'
// asdlökfjasdf abc äalsdfkgjölsaädkfgj xyz
```

## Explanation

The search expression matches the whole line as anchored by `^` and `$`, if it contains "abc" and "xyz" somewhere to its right. This whole match is remembered because it is enclosed in `(`...`)`, so that we may back-reference it in the replacement. There we just prepend `//`  to the whole match which we insert with its back-reference `\1`.

The `-E` (aka. use extended regular expressions) saves us escaping the brackets.

Comment: Your pattern only matches if `xyz` is after `abc`.

Comment: I tried this. But facing this error.

sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Barmar , that is exactly what the OP wanted to achieve, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @firebolt , that `-E` option needs to be a capital "e", not lower-case. Could you try again with an upper case "e"?

Comment: Only if you interpret "1st string" and "2nd string" to refer to their order on the line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/abc/{/xyz/s#^#//#}' file
```

Match `abc` then match `xyz` and insert at the start of the line `//`.

Alternatives:

```
sed '/abc/!b;/xyz/s#^#//#' file

sed '/abc/!b;/xyz/!b;s#^#//#' file

sed 's/abc/&/;T;/xyz/s#^#//#' file

sed 's/abc/&/;T;s/xyz/&/;T;s#^#//#' file

sed '/abc/{/xyz/{s#^#//#}}' file

sed '/abc.*xyz\|xyz.*abc/s#^#//#' file

sed 's#.*\(abc.*xyz\|xyz.*abc\)#//&#' file

sed 's/.*abc.*/echo "&"|sed "\\#xyz#s#^#\/\/#"/e' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
awk '/abc/ && /xyz/{print "//" $0}' myfile
```

To change the original file using GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace '/abc/ && /xyz/{print "//" $0}' myfile
```

or any awk:

```
awk '/abc/ && /xyz/{print "//" $0}' myfile > tmp && mv tmp myfile
```